# how to add suffix with form name in javascript

Tags: javascript

hi I have a function in javascript in which I am accessing the hidden value of a form. I want to add a suffix in javascript. I am try like this

```
function add_new_certification(vid)
{
    var sr=document.form_vid.hidden.value;
    alert(sr);

}
```

I want to concate vid value with form name. How Can I do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function add_new_certification(vid) {   
   var fn = 'form_' + vid;  
   var sr=document[fn].hidden.value;     
   alert(sr);  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use square bracket notation if you want to access a property when you have its name stored in a string.

```
foo['b' + 'ar']
```

is the same as

```
foo.bar
```